# how to create multiple new arrays from existing multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below multi dimensional array i want to make a new array from taking each array's first element and make one array than after second element of each array and make a new array, i did tried `for` loop and `foreach` but i can't able to make it help me to solve this please, Thank you in advance.

the below is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 40
                    [label] => SCIENCE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 100
                    [label] => SCIENCE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 89
                    [label] => SCIENCE
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 72
                    [label] => MATHEMATICS
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 20
                    [label] => MATHEMATICS
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 70
                    [label] => MATHEMATICS
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 85
                    [label] => MATHEMATICS
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 66
                    [label] => ENGLISH
                )

        )

)
```

I want my first new array be like

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 40
                    [label] => SCIENCE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 72
                    [label] => MATHEMATICS
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 66
                    [label] => ENGLISH
                )

        )
```

My second new array be like

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 100
                    [label] => SCIENCE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 20
                    [label] => MATHEMATICS
                )
        )
```

Comment: You always want to arrays as output or is it depending on the input array?

Comment: `array_column()` should be able to help.

Comment: depending on the in put array.

Comment: Do you mind telling how it depends or are we going to try and read your mind?

Comment: @Andreas sir i can't get you actually ll you please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreach loop the array with $key and you will be able to get the other items easily with array_column.

```
foreach($arr[0] as $key => $sub){
     $new[$key] = array_column($arr, $key);
}
```

Now $new will have three items (the same as first subarray).

---

To fix what you asked for I have to loop and find the max count of the arrays.

```
$max =0;
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $max = max($max, count($sub));
}
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
    $new[$i] = array_column($arr, $i);
}
```

Comment: this answer works me fine but the answer miss one array i.e it's gave me three new array but miss one from mathemetics array how to get that too.

Comment: @sameerkumar that is what I asked you about in comments above, kind off. I can fix it but Splashes answer will be better even if I fix it so just go with that.

Comment: sorry i didn't see that comment, but ll you please let me know how can i able to get the max of sub array which i can able to loop and get the desire output.

Comment: I just edited the answer. But as I said go with the other answer

Comment: Thank You a lot Mr. @andreas it's working now thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can transpose an array, remove empty entries and take needed row. In the case your result will be in `$res[0]` and `$res[1]` arrays

```
$res = array_map('array_filter', array_map(null, ...$a));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1050351)

Comment: Nicly done! Like how you got the fourth item as well

Comment: @splash58 i just copy and paste your code but it doesn't gave me any out put sorry am not that experienced in programming it's ended with an error. `syntax error, unexpected '.' `

Comment: @sameerkumar what a version of php do you use?

Comment: i am using 5.5.34

Comment: You can `array_unshift($a, null);` and then `call_user_func_array($a);` instead of `array_map(null, ...$a);` (the [splat](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) operator was introduced in 5.6)

Comment: Yes Thank you it's the answer what i want .